# Is there a way to email a link inviting people to sign up for an event that will be connect to their contact ID?

Tags: civievent, tokens, checksum

I have a list of people who I want to encourage to sign up for an event. I can send a link that allows them to update their contact information, using the contact hash. What I would like to do is send them a similar link that would create a new event registration for their contact ID. This would solve a couple problems:

- Avoid duplicate contact entries from being created.
- Auto-populate contact fields make the user experience more pleasant.

Am I missing a way to do this, or is there a way to implement it short of a new core feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contact checksum works equally well for a CiviEvent registration as it does for updating their contact info via a profile.  The [tokens page of the wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens) has a section at the bottom that shows how to format the URL based on your CMS:

**Checksum for Event Registration Pages**: To send people to an event registration page use this path where N is the ID of your event:

```
Drupal: http://www.myorganization.org/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=N&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}
Joomla!: http://www.myorganization.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=N&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}
WordPress: http://www.myorganization.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=N&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}
```

**Alternate approach**: Using checksums  is a little complicated for some folks, especially end users!  To make your life simpler, consider installing the [Fancy Tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/fancy-tokens) extension.  This gives you drop-in tokens for your next several events that include the checksum automatically.